# C++ template allows discard of const reference qualifier

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

**Why does this code compile?** (tested with g++ and clang++)

The following code is for a factory method that accepts a function and creates a forwarding std::function out of it. As you can see, the lambda inside accepts `const Arg&` arguments and forwards them to the given function.

In `main()` I use `factory()` to create a forwarder to `test_func()`, which accepts a non-const reference parameter. What I don't understand is why this doesn't produce an error about discarding the const qualifier from the argument.

Note that indeed the instance of the class `C`, created in `main()`, is passed without creating any copies.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
        C() {}

        C(const C&)
        {
                std::cout << "C copy\n";
        }
};

int test_func(C& cref)
{
        return 0;
}

template<typename Ret, typename... Arg>
std::function<Ret (const Arg&...)> factory(Ret (*func) (Arg...))
{
        return [ func ] (const Arg&... arg) -> Ret {
                return (func)(arg...);
        };
}

int main() {
        auto caller = factory(test_func);
        C c;
        caller(c);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: why Ret (*func) (Arg...) and not Ret (*func) (const Arg&...) ?

Comment: With `Arg` == `C&`, `const Arg&` (or `Arg const&`) == `C& const&` == `C&`.

Comment: @ForEveR I don't want to assume anything on the types of the function I'm forwarding to, supposedly to make it work with any function (this is just a reduced example of something else I was trying to do)

Comment: then you need perfect forwarding

Comment: @Xeo I didn't know that... why don't you put this in an answer with a proper reference to a resource that explains it (e.g. the C++ standard or an article). I understand whay you're saying, but I never thought the const can be removed this way.

Comment: @BЈовић Can you put that in code? I actually tried perfect forwarding, but it created extra copies of the arguments that I couldn't explain

Comment: As @Xeo said, `C& const& == C&`. §8.3.2/1 states: "Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument (14.3), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored."

Comment: @MWid Eventually I found that myself. However, it looks like the same text is modified in the next standard draft and does not include templates anymore: "Cv-qualiﬁed references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualiﬁers are introduced
through the use of a typedef-name (7.1.3, 14.1) or decltype-speciﬁcer (7.1.6.2), in which case the cv-qualiﬁers
are ignored." Not sure what this means, but I understand the current situation. Found here: http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf

Comment: @gnobal Templates are still included. An _identifier_ of a _type-parameter_ is a _typedef-name_ (if the identifier does not follow an ellipsis). This is §14.1/3.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use perfect forwarding (see Scott Meyers's presentation on [Universal reference](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)).

In your case, it should be :

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class C
{
public:
        C() {}

        C(const C&)
        {
                std::cout << "C copy\n";
        }
};

int test_func(const C& )
{
        return 0;
}

template<typename Ret, typename... Arg>
std::function<Ret (Arg...)> factory(Ret (*func) (Arg...))
{
        return [ func ] (Arg&&... arg) -> Ret {
                return func(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
        };
}

int main() {
        auto caller = factory(test_func);
        const C c;
        caller(c);
}
```

Take a note that I changed `C c;` to `const C c;` in your `main()`, and I modified the test_func.

---

If you want to avoid creating copies, you have to make sure the test_func function it not taking by value. It should take by reference (const of non-const).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now if I use this code for a `test_func(C c)` (that accepts a value type) it makes 4 copies of C, which I don't understand why and is unacceptable (I would like perfect forwarding to make as many copies as it would make if I simply called the function myself)

Comment: @gnobal You do not have move constructor, that is why it calls copy constructor

Comment: I understand, but why 4 copies? If it was perfectly forwarded, I would expect exactly 1 copy, as if I had called `test_func(c)` myself.

Comment: @gnobal I had a bug. Now only 3 copies. 1st to pass to function object. 2nd to pass to func. 3rd to pass to test_func

Comment: @gnobal there is some perfect forwarding, but no single fixed signature can perfect forward.  So an intermediate stage is done perfectly.  A custom written override_function_set that exposes an exponential number of `operator()` overloads could perfect forward perfectly (2^n overloads for `n` by-value arguments).  It would be amusing to write, but rarely practical.

Comment: @BЈовић and Yakk Thanks. I guess the "perfect" in "perfect forwarding" confused me. Eventually to create the least amount of copies it appears as though the const& solution is the right one for me because it doesn't produce any extra copies. I'm still trying to find out why the original code posted in the question builds (Xeo's comment helps)

Comment: @BЈовић: I'm 100% sure Scott Meyers coined the term "universal reference" but I believe it wasn't him who coined the term "perfect forwarding".

Comment: @CassioNeri I am not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that nonsense. Fixed now. Thanks